# Are questions about first language learning on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a newborn at home, he is not in the age (yet) to be able to learn a language. It always intrigued me how that process works and I have a few questions about it.

Are questions regarding first language acquisition on topic here? Or should I ask them, perhaps in [parenting SE](http://parenting.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 5):

First Language Acquisition is still language acquisition.

However, questions that are leaning more toward *parenting* rather than language learning are more likely to be perceived as off-topic and would be a better fit over on Parenting.SE.

Comment: @ANeves, it did seem a little harsh, I've toned the wording down a bit now

Answer (score 2):

They are on-topic here, as long as it is about learning the language as such. They are probably on-topic on parenting SE as well, though. So I guess it depends on which focus you want to have.

Note that language learning, starts from before birth :-)

Answer (score 0):

That topic is valid for a number of sites: this one, Parenting, and Linguistics. Depending on what you are looking to learn will dictate which StackExchange community can best help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's on-topic as long as i**t's about the process/method/technique used to learn a language**, regardless of whether this is your child's first or second language.

Keep in mind, however, that there is a fine line between Parenting and Language Learning. Any questions about the behavior of your child, specifically, is off-topic here.

*How can I motivate my child to read a book in language A to learn it everyday?* **is off-topic.**

*How does my baby's brain differentiate between different words and eventually learn their definitions without formal education when he is learning his first language?* **is on-topic (although quite wordy and could use some simplifying).**